# How to create Web based visual Process Designer?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax, business-process-management

I have been ask to design web based process designer (Business Process designer) in asp.net/c# . I have currently one programmer in my team and we have two months for this.We have found some open source BPM designers but we want to design our own as for our learning thirst?
please give suggestions

Comment: Please suggest some open source BPM process designer as well that can be integrated in our project.

Comment: you say you already have found some?

Comment: Yes but if any body has used any thing similar then their comments will be great help.

Comment: we have no real customer paying but our management wants to add this functionality to our existing product , we have two months to release new version and they just told me about this req , they can cancel this idea on my suggestion but i thought it could be a challenge so i was evaluating the options. – Adeel  an hour ago  [delete this comment]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [js-graph-it](http://js-graph-it.sourceforge.net/) which is a javascript and CSS based diagramming technology. Though not a complete solution, it could be something you can start with.

Answer (score 1):

"but we want to design our own as for our learning thirst"

This statement is concerning.  You also say you have 1 programmer and the 2 months to complete the system.  With those sorts of constraints I would say building anything but a simple/small system is quite unrealistic.

Do you have any real (ie paying) customers?

Is yes, then making a fundamental design choice to suit your desire to learn rather then the customers priorities, is very irresponsble to your customers.

If no, then I guess you are free to follow your own whims for learning, however learning about an existing option is also a great way to further knowledge.

In a professional situation, I would first evaluate existing options very carefully and only once I am sure they are lacking in certain key requirements, consider writing myself.  Writing it myself doesn't happen very often.

Sorry to be a bit critical, however I've seen this sort of thng "end in tears" many times if the wrong choice is made.

Comment: No we have no real customer paying but our management wants to add this functionality to our existing product , we have two months to release new version and they just told me about this req , they can cancel this idea on my suggestion but i thought it could be a challenge so i was evaluating the options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Silverlight Canvas to design the work flow. you can create the work flow boxes as an asset to the workflow designer and allow user to drag drop those workflow boxes on canvas. then use arrows to connect the boxes. this will mark the flow between the proceesses

then export that process to XML or in DB where ever you want to save and then you make your own code to process that xml and execute the conditions defined in the workflow.

so over all there will be 3 parts of that application.

1. Silverlight based workflow Designer application
2. a Database Connector Service which will interact Designer with Database
3. A Process Execution Engine which will execute that workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I may get flammed for not matching the tags you provided; however, recently I found an application online that I was highly impressed with.  It was written in **flash** of all things and I have yet to find a slicker interface for storyboarding on any web site.  The application is called [imagination cubed](http://www.imaginationcubed.com/index.php).  I know it is unconventional to place shapes and flow diagrams using such a fun to use interface... but I find it loads better than crusty applicaitons on the market today.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider your customer. Would it not be better to deliver a nearly there existing solution quickly (possibly as a v1) and then use the time saved to educate yourselves? This way you not only gain in productivity and kudos but can actually get your users to submit real world experience and thus make any your v2 so much better?